# Apachectl prints weird error and dies when PHP7.2 is loaded. Why?

Tags: php, apache2, php-7.2

sudo apachectl configtest prints this:

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl: line 92: 78131 Killed: 9               $HTTPD -t
```

Why?? I tried to restart it several times. If PHP7 module is not loaded, everything works fine, but otherwise it prints this crap.

Moreover, the exact same PHP version (PHP 7.2) worked fine just yesterday. The mac has been recently updated though, this is Catalina 10.15.7, running Apache 2 (system default).

Maybe it's the update? How can use PHP7 now? Also tried to upgrade to PHP 7.3, but the result is the same..

Pleas help!!

EDIT:

I tested with PHP 7.4 as well, same..

All PHP versions have been installed via homebrew, so they should be fine.

Don't know what's going on...

Comment: any update on this, I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

When I make `sudo apachectl -k restart`, I have the same error

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl: line 92: 16415 Killed: 9               $HTTPD "$@"
```

I don't have the error when I comment `LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.4/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so` and uncomment `LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so`.

I mean I can use php preinstalled with Cantalina but I can't use php installed by homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

The actual problem is MAC's default `apachectl` which keeps raising issues on each MAC update. So need to unload it and load the `homebrew` `httpd`.

These are the steps:

1. Comment php module in `httpd.conf` and then restart apache using `sudo apachectl -k restart`

(this is necessary because if you dont do that the process will be detached from `launchctl` and would still be running, giving you the error `org.apache.httpd.plist could not find specified service` on the next steps)

2. Now stop apache and unload it by using these commands:

```
sudo apachectl stop
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

3. Now use these commands to install apache from homebrew and make it load as service:

```
brew install httpd
sudo brew services start httpd
```

4. Now configure your new apache instance having the conf file on this location:
   `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`.
5. When done, just restart